# Solving $ x+2\cos(x)=0 $

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to apologise, this problem is probably ridiculously easy for nearly all of you, but I still don't know how to solve it...

The equation is:

> $$ x+2\cos(x)=0 $$

I would like simple solutions, if possible

**EDIT**

I was asking the question because I had to analyse function $$ f(x)=x+2\cos(x) $$ and I wanted to find its zeroes (roots) and I wanted to do it in an analytical way.

Comment: In the “shopping list” I give my students when talking about “study of functions”, there notably isn't “find the zeros”. Indeed, one of the reasons for studying a function is localizing, if any, its zeros. Of course, *if* the zeros can be found with algebraic methods, it's good to find them in advance, but it shouldn't a mandatory preliminary step in the study of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not ridicously easy. In fact, it is impossible.

I assume that you want a simple formula or expression to solve the equation, but there is none.

All that can be done is:

- To prove that the equation has a solution.
- To find arbitrarily good approximations of the solution (with increasing effort).

Comment: Wow, I had no idea, this looked pretty basic to me... How come it can't be solved analytically? 

Bascially, the reason I want to solve this is because I need to analyse function $ f(x) = x + 2\cos(x) $.. I began, determined $D=\mathbb{R} \quad R=\mathbb{R} $ and tried to continue with roots (zeroes)...

Comment: As a rule of thumb, equations can't be solved analytically ! The ones that can are essentially polynomials of a low degree. (And a few others with transcendental functions, when they can be reduced to polynomial forms.)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot solve this analytically. You can have some intuition about the solution using, for example, Taylor series (if possible).

$$\cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$$

Stopping here.

$$x + 2 - x^2 = 0$$

$$x^2 - x - 2 = 0$$

$$x_1 = 2 ~~~~~~~~~~~ x_2 = -1$$

In which only the second solution gives you a quite good approximation of the real solution. But this is not a very effective way, unless you go on with orders.

Comment: as further justification of this method, the solution of the equation should happen close to the origin

Comment: @qbert That is true too! I actually did not want to post it because I ignored if the OP were familiar with TS...

Comment: I am. But thanks for both of your answers!

Comment: the value $-1$ is a very good starting point for using Newton's method. the convergence is superfast (the first iteration is off only by something like 0.0016%)

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$f'(x)=1-2\sin x=0$$ giving $x=\pi/6+2k\pi,5\pi/6+2k\pi$.

These are the locations of the extrema. As you can verify, only $[-5\pi/6,\pi/6]$ corresponds to a change of sign, hence $f$ has a single root, in this range.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Obviously, the root of $\ds{\ x + 2\cos\pars{x} = 0\ }$ belongs to $\ds{\bracks{-2,2}}$. Since $\ds{\ x + 2\cos\pars{x} > 0}$ when $\ds{x \in \bracks{0,2}}$ and $\ds{\ x + 2\cos\pars{x}}$ has different sign in
>   $\ds{x = -2}$ and $\ds{x = 0}$ we can try to find the root in $\ds{\bracks{-2,0}}$ with the starting point $\ds{x_{0} = \pars{-2 + 0}/2 = -1}$
>   and the $\texttt{Newton-Rapson Method}$: $\ds{x_{n} = x_{n - 1} - \bracks{x_{n - 1} + 2\cos\pars{x_{n - 1}}}/\bracks{1 - 2\sin\pars{x_{n - 1}}}}$.

$\ds{\large\texttt{javascript}}$ code:

```
// nr0.js
"use strict";
var df = function (x) { return 1.0 - 2.0*Math.sin(x); };
var  f = function (x) { return x + 2.0*Math.cos(x); };
var  n = 0;
var  s = "";
var  x = (-2.0 + 0.0)/2.0; // x0 = -1

do {
    s += "x = " + x + "\,   x + 2cos(x) = " + f(x) + "\n" ;
    x -= f(x)/df(x);
} while (++n < 4);

s += "x = " + x + "\,   x + 2cos(x) = " + f(x) + "\n" ;
console.log(s);
```

Result:

```
x = -1,                    x + 2cos(x) =  0.08060461173627953
x = -1.0300433675603586,   x + 2cos(x) = -0.00048003651998573815
x = -1.0298665352529512,   x + 2cos(x) = -1.6098630428729166e-8
x = -1.0298665293222589,   x + 2cos(x) =  0
x = -1.0298665293222589,   x + 2cos(x) =  0
```

$\ds{\bbox[#efe,0.5em,border:0.1em groove navy]{root \approx -1.0298665293222589}}$